# jOOQ: How can I include a "some_field IS NULL" predicate in the projection?

Tags: java, jooq

This compiles, but it seems a bit roundabout:

```
List<Field<?>> selectFields = new ArrayList<>();
selectFields.add(DSL.field(MY_TABLE.SOME_FIELD.isNull()).as("field_alias"));
```

The `field()` call is required because `isNull()` returns a `Condition`, whereas I think I need a `Field`. Is there a better way? Maybe an `isNull()` that returns something that can be used directly in a `select()`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `jooq`, but could it be done with using a ternary operator?

Comment: SQL doesn't have a ternary operator, so I'm not sure how this would work. jOOQ tends to represent SQL operators and functions as methods in Java. The part I can't figure out is how jOOQ would represent a "SELECT name IS NULL FROM person".

Comment: Well, long time ago, when I used MySql, there was a possibility to write something like this: `insert into table (column) (select if('condition is true', true value, false value)) from table)`. IDK if jooq can do this.

Comment: You already answered your question. Use [`DSL.field(Condition)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field-org.jooq.Condition-)

Comment: @LukasEder Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`DSL.field(Condition)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field-org.jooq.Condition-) (which you're already using) is the way to go here.

There have been contemplations about letting `Condition` extends `Field<Boolean>`: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3867, but the change would be too risky in terms of backwards compatibility.